# Variable in data keeps reverting to true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, boolean

I've probably done this a thousand times now. Simple procedure where if I click on an element, I access a method and change a variable in data(). Only now, whenever I do that the variable keeps toggling. The variable is originally set to false, there's an element when if clicked toggles that variable to true. There's another element that when clicked sets the variable to false. Only whenever that variable is set to false again it keeps toggling back to true. I checked the inspector and noticed that whenever the variable is set back to false it automatically reverts back to true.

I created a new component, deleted everything that doesn't have to do with the toggling and that behavior still persists. Sometimes when I keep clicking on the element it'll maintain false but the number of clicks required seems to be random. Could this be a bug?

This is the component

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full text-black">
    <div
      v-if="editing"
      class="flex justify-between items-center"
    >
      <div class="block flex justify-center items-center h-4">
        <div class="icon-teal cursor-pointer w-6 mr-4">
          <img
            src="/svgs/check.svg"
            alt
            @click="save($event)"
          >
        </div>

        <div
          class="block relative cursor-pointer w-4 h-4"
          v-on:click="deactivate($event)"
        >
          <img
            class="icon-red colorize-teal "
            src="/svgs/close.svg"
            alt
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      v-else
      class="flex justify-between items-center"
    >
      <p class="w-3/5 px-4 py-3 h-12">text</p>

      <div
        class="block cursor-pointer icon-grey colorize-teal w-5"
        @click="activateField($event)"
      >
        <img
          class
          src="/svgs/pen.svg"
          alt
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      editing: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activateField (event) {
      this.editing = true;
    },

    deactivate (event) {
      this.editing = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?
Also try doing it inline: `@click="myToggleVar = !myToggleVar"`

Comment: try `@click.stop=....`

Comment: Updated with relevant component.

Comment: I tried again with .stop and it seems to have solved the issue. Why would it ever reset the variable to true when the accessed method only sets the variable to false? Seems very strange.

Comment: Why are you sending the event, you are not using it all? it should be removed from the functions and inline. This may help as well. I think what is happening is that once you call the function with the `$event` both functions are executed

Comment: @Michael This is the stripped down version of the component. The original version uses the event on the clicked element to add/remove css classes on the target element.

Comment: The event is implicitly passed to the function do not call it

Comment: Oh alright, didn't know about that. Thanks!